# Convergence without metric or topology or sigma field.

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

You can set some kind of convergence in a space of functions without using some metric or topology or sigma field?

Comment: So, convergence-a.e. does not fit because it goes via the definition of a $\sigma$-field?

Comment: a.e. convergence involves a topology or a metric or the like on the codomain.  But "a.e." is about the domain.

Comment: @Ilya I would suppose so, since for convergence a.e, you need some notion of convergence already, which you would then relax over the measure zero sets..

Comment: The convergence in metric depends on a collection of subsets. Namely the topology generated by the metric. The a.e. convergence  depends of a collection of subsets ( and the measure too). Namely the sigma field. It seems to me that the notion of convergence depends on a collection of sets convenient. My question would be in that direction. Not specific to my question does not limit the possibilities.

Comment: @Michael: I didn't get your comment, sorry. A.e. is about a domain - but convergence a.e. does not involve any topology on the codomain, does it?

Comment: The meaning of the statement $\lim\limits_n f_n(x) = f(x)$ for _almost all_ $x$ in the domain depends on the meaning of the statement that $\lim\limits_n f_n(x) = f(x)$ for some particular $x$ in the domain.  The terms $f_n(x)$ belong to the codomain.  When you talk about a sequence of points in the codomain converging to a point in the codomain, that involves a topology or metric or the like in the codomain.

Comment: So how do we talk about convergence - well we have an indexed sequence of points which get "close" to a limit point, and which get (in some general sense) "closer" as the index increases that they become (and this is a expression to avoid "limit") "so close as to be indistinguishable" from it. Now there is probably a way of doing this with specific sequences and limits which avoids something like topology - but to work for all points of the space and all sequences of interest, you have to capture a general concept - as topology does.

Comment: It seems to me that the notion of Convergence requires some notion of closeness of points, which I cannot think of a way to do that without a collection of privileged sets to work with. But, I am no expert.

Comment: If it has any relevance: There is the notion of *convergence spaces*, which generalize topological spaces.

Comment: Doesn't pointwise convergence fit this definition?

Comment: @Michael: ah, sure - I confused the codomain with the space of functions itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a trifle of an example that seems to suffice your requirement.

Let $A$ and $B$ be any sets, and consider the space $B^A$ of functions from $A$ to $B$. Also, let $\omega$ be a [nonprincipal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrafilter#Types_and_existence_of_ultrafilters) [ultrafilter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrafilter#Formal_definition) on $\mathbb{N}$. That is, $\omega$ is a maximal filter on $\mathbb{N}$ that contains no finite sets. (The existence of such filter is ensured by the Axiom of Choice.)

Then for a sequence $(f_n) \subset B^A$ of functions and a function $f \in B^A$, we say
$$ f_n \stackrel{\omega}{\longrightarrow}f$$
if for every $x \in A$, the set $\{ n \in \mathbb{N} : f_n (x) = f(x) \}$ is contained in $\omega$.

It is easy to prove the uniqueness of the limit, and if there is an algebraic structure on $B$, it easily follows that this notion of limit is compatible with the operations on $B$.

But it does not capture any useful concept of 'closeness' (rather, it is just a description incognito of 'equal a.e. $n$ pointwise'), so it seems of little importance to consider this kind of notion.

Comment: Trifle perhaps, but also large research area.

Comment: It’s arguably still topological: it’s just topological $\omega$-convergence when $B$ is given the discrete topology.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Im sorry if my answer seemed to disrespect a certain branch of mathematics. I'm not intended to disparage the ultrafilter concept. Rather, I just wanted to figure out that the *particulal instance* described in the body text is trivial.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott : And it also conceals nearly a concept of measure since ultrafilter is a special cond of finite additive measure on the power set of natural numbers. What I tried is to give an example which is deprived of many interesting structures.

Comment: I think that you probably did remove about as much topology and measure as can be removed.